# SharePoint Online Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, power-automate, flow

I am currently working in a Power Automate Flow that needs a calculated column that acts as a counter towards an expiration date to be compared in an if statement to send alerts to multiple users letting them know "Hey your cert is expired, please re-take the cert again".

In order to do this I would like to have a calculated column that automatically counts days left towards the expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following calculated formula:

```
=DATEDIF(TODAY(),[expired date],"d")
```

As a result, it will get the left days:

[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Is this answer helpful for you? Please feel free to reply.